# What camera calibration algorithm does OpenCV use for non co-planar calibration rig?

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I have been working with Zhang's homography technique till now for my camera calibration. But the accuracy of the calibration is not sufficient (After taking necessary actions to improve: Example : spanning the whole FOV, variation in distance, etc.)

I have read in a few literature that non-coplanar calibration rig would give better results. I don't understand the exact reason behind this suggestion. If someone could explain to me how is accuracy improved, it would be good. Even better, would be is to point me to the algorithm that is used in OpenCV for non co-planar calibration rigs.

Based on OpenCV [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#calibratecamera), the algorithm has been implemented based on Bouguet's [Camera Calibration ToolBox](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/index.html#links). But, I am not sure whether OpenCV uses Heikkila's approach (3rd example) or Bakstein and Halir's approach (4th example). If nothing helps, I am planning on going through OpenCV source code.

Comment: I don't think opencv camera calibration for non-planar rig works. Did you get a chance to understand, and if possible, get another library for calibration using non-planar rig?